# Triggering the catch block even when response is accurate with status 200

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have a react application, making a simple post request through Node and express. The data reaches the correct end point, stores properly, and returns data with a status(200). Everything works as it should, but the request that was made inside a try catch block always dispatches the type: ERROR from the catch block.

This is from the express end,

```
try {
    const newQuestion = new Question({
      question,
      difficulty,
      correctAnswer,
      wrongAnswerOne,
      wrongAnswerTwo,
      wrongAnswerThree,
      submittedBy: {
        name,
        email,
        organization
      }
    });
    const addQuestion = await newQuestion.save();
    console.log(addQuestion);
    res.json(addQuestion);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    res.status(500).send("Error at question POST");
  }
```

And this from the client side React.

```
 try {
    const res = await axios.post("/questions", question, config);
    console.log("res", res);
    dispatch({
      type: ADD_QUESTION,
      payload: res.data
    });
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: QUESTION_ERROR,
      payload: err.data
    });
  }
};
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: What is the error it gives?

Comment: what does that console log show?

Comment: On both ends the console.log appears as it should. On the backend it logs the req.body accurately, and the response is just sending that back and that reaches the front end accurately too, but it still sends to the catch block.